# Why is it showing "False" in leetcode while it is showing True while doing it on my own in VSCode

Tags: python, feed, perfect-numbers

I am new to programming and I tried some of the easy leet code problems. When I run the code on my own it returns the correct boolean value but when I run in leetcode it returns the opposite. Like it returns True in vs code while it returns false in Leetcode. It is a simple program to check if it is a perfect number or not.

```
class Solution:
    def checkPerfectNumber(self, num: int) -> bool:
        num = int(input("Enter number: "))
        sum = 0
    
        for i in range(1,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                sum = sum + i

        if sum == num:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Also, remember that it is `True/False`, not `true/false`.  Did you retype this?

Comment: You can simplify your code by just doing `return num == sum` instead of your `if num == sum` And without knowing the specifications of your problem: are you sure you are expected to get the `input` within the function and not use the parameter provided to the function?

Answer (score 1):

You are not expected to read a value using `input`.  The correct value is passed in to the function in the `num` parameter, which you throw away.  If you want to TEST this, add a line at the end like

```
print(Solution().checkPerfectNumber(int(input("Enter number:"))))
```